# aws s3 cp inside a Dockerfile return permission denied

Tags: docker, amazon-s3

I got surprised to see when `RUN aws s3 cp s3://<bucket_name>/application_artefacts/com-sdk/sdk_webserver-21.2.0-snapshot.tar.gz .` return error when it is executed from a Dockerfile. The Dockerfile is build inside a AWS instance.

`download failed: s3://<bucket-name>/application_artefacts/com-sdk/sdk_webserver-21.2.0-snapshot.tar.gz to ./pcc_webserver-21.2.0-snapshot.tar.gz [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/app/sdk_webserver-21.2.0-snapshot.tar.gz.9520ab29'`

However, `aws s3 cp s3://<bucket_name>/application_artefacts/com-sdk/sdk_webserver-21.2.0-snapshot.tar.gz .` works properly inside AWS instance.

Complete Dockerfile

```
FROM xxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/api-builder-jdk-corretto8:latest
ARG profile
WORKDIR /app
RUN aws s3 cp s3://<bucket-name>/application_artefacts/com-sdk/sdk_webserver-21.2.0-snapshot.tar.gz .
RUN aws s3 cp s3://<bucket-name>/application_artefacts/com-sdk/sdk_appserver-21.2.0-snapshot.tar.gz .
RUN tar xvf /app/sdk_webserver-21.2.0-snapshot.tar.gz
RUN tar xvf /app/sdk_appserver-21.2.0-snapshot.tar.gz
ENTRYPOINT []
```

Comment: Are the aws credentials available in the Dockerfile?

Comment: @Paolo do we need credentials inside a Dockerfile?. I am building the Dockerfile inside an AWS instance which is already having credentials.

Comment: Credentials on the instance itself will not be present on the containers running there, unless it's defined explicitly.

Comment: The "Permission denied: /app/..." sounds like a _local_ permission error, not an AWS credential issue.  In the base image, what are the permissions on `/app`, and is there an alternate `USER`?  (Does switching to `USER root` and then back help?)

Answer (score 1):

When you run `aws ...` locally environment variables and filesystem is available and accessable for aws-cli.

For example if you have `~/.aws/credentials` (it's created by `aws configure`) it will be used to retrieve your key and token. Or you have `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables with credentials in place.

From another hand - whatever you run in Docker had it's own, isolated context. So you need to pass both environment and files inside the container explicitly - docker has `-v` and `-e` options for that.

UPD: My answer is relevant when when running images, not when building them.

Comment: @llia Kondrashov, i am not assuming any role or running the Dockerfile from local. I am running inside an instance where it allows to perform any AWS aws-cli command. Also, it should return credentials error rather permission denied error.
For e.g. i changed the Dockerfile only to list all the buckets and i got Access denied error.

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied

Comment: If the EC2 instance has an instance profile with an IAM role, and it can get credentials via the http://169.254.169.254/ EC2 metadata service, this will work even from within a Dockerfile without any special setup.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause of the issue and it is due to the WORKDIR /app instruction added in the Dockerfile. Giving permission to this folder or removing `WORKDIR /app`  from the Dockerfile allows copy from s3 bucket.